# How to tell UITableView that a self-sizing cell's height is about to change?

Tags: ios, uitableview, autolayout

I've got a UITableView whose contents are somewhat dynamic. It seems like every time I resize them, I hit this error:

```
Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.

    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. Try this: (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 

(

    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x15dbabf0 WKWebView:0x15da1650.top == UITableViewCellContentView:0x15eaedb0.topMargin>",

    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x15dbac20 UITableViewCellContentView:0x15eaedb0.bottomMargin == WKWebView:0x15da1650.bottom>",

    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x15db1360 V:[WKWebView:0x15da1650(158)]>",

    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x15ed0c00 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Height' V:[UITableViewCellContentView:0x15eaedb0(43.5)]>"

)
```

It's that last one - the one labeled `UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Height` - that is breaking things. I want to get rid of it, or set it to a breaking priority, or something - but I can't seem to be able to tell UITableView to break it. I've tried every possible combination of `setNeedsUpdateConstraints` and `setNeedsLayout` on various views. I've tried removing all the constraints from the cell's `contentView` on `updateConstraints`. I've tried just calling `beginUpdates` and `endUpdates` - in that case, `updateConstraints` is never called & the constraints are not re-evaluated.

I'm at a loss, here. Without self-sizing cells, just calling begin/endUpdates used to trigger a re-calculation of the cell's dimensions. How do I do it now?

Comment: You need to set constraint for the cell properly as you want and then need to calculate the height correctly..

Comment: @TamilKing I'm talking about self-sizing table view cells in iOS 8. Check out the video for *What's New in Table and Collection Views* from WWDC 2014.

Comment: remove cell and add it back with new contracts 
and give height of cell with heightForRowAtIndexPath

Comment: @ShoaibSarwarCheema As I said above - I'm talking about self-sizing table view cells. Also, I tried reloading the cell and giving UITableView the same cell instance - same problem. In this case, the cell's sizing is coming from a WKWebView so that's not a great solution.

Comment: I'm having a similar issue with dynamic table view cell sizing. I followed this tutorial: http://www.raywenderlich.com/87975/dynamic-table-view-cell-height-ios-8-swift which worked perfectly, except that when I tried to use the same concepts in my own table view implementation, I couldn't get it to work. It should work, except that this "UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Height" is incorrect and breaks all my constraints. It won't adjust itself to my cell's layout like I want it to :(

Comment: I too hit the autolayout following the example at raywenderlich. What resolved the issue for me after a lot of trial and error was to remove the calls to  
[sizingCell setNeedsLayout];
[sizingCell layoutIfNeeded]; from the method  calculateHeightForConfiguredSizingCell everything still appears to work and no longer get the autolayput warning. (IOS8+)

Answer (score 0):

The WKWebView which you are using inside the content view is the most possible cause of breaking constraints. Also the height of any webView can be calculated only when the WebView has finished loading. For e.g in UIWebView the height of the UIWebView can be fetched appropriately only in the delgate method "didFinishLoadingWebView" method.

Also, the 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Height' constraints supposedly does not get satisfied as the cell's intrinsic height calculated probably has a different value. Hence one can lower the priority of the relevant cell constraint to allow UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Height to have precedence.