# How to update self-sizing tableview's height?

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift2

If I put a custom view in a cell , how can I notify tableview to update cell's height if my custom view's height has changed? I tried invalidateIntrinsicContentSize but that doesn't work. ReloadData works but I doubt whether using

```
self.superview?.superview?.superview as! UITableView).reloadData()
```

is a good implementation.
I have seen a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28059581/how-to-tell-uitableview-that-a-self-sizing-cells-height-is-about-to-change) but that's all about view from standard library. And [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28955612/self-sizing-uitableviewcell-not-recalculate-content-size-when-subview-instrinsic) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30468852/ios-8-self-sizing-cells-with-changing-height) have no answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are thinking in the right direction. However there are two problems with your approach:

1. `reloadData` reloads the whole table view and it does not animate the change.
2. Moving up the superview chain is bound to break when Apple changes the `UITableView` view hierarchy. They have done that before, so they might do it again.

To fix the first issue you should call `reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:` instead. That only reloads the cells that you specify in the indexPath array. So you pass it an array that only contains the indexPath of your cell.

The second issue is a bit trickier because a `UITableViewCell` has no reference to its `UITableView` (and it shouldn't). So it cannot tell the `UITableView` directly to reload the cell.

You can give each cell a closure that it should execute whenever its height has changed. So you just add a closure property in your custom cell:

```
class YourCustomTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    var resizeClosure: (() -> Void)?
    ...
```

And you set this closure in your `UITableViewControllerDataSource` when you dequeue the cell:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell:UITableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("YourCustomCellIdentifier", forIndexPath: indexPath)
        if let customCell = cell as? YourCustomTableViewCell {
            customCell.resizeClosure = { [weak cell, weak tableView] in
                if let currentIndexPath = tableView?.indexPathForCell(cell!) {
                    tableView?.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([currentIndexPath], withRowAnimation: .Automatic)
                }
            }
        }

        return cell
    }
```

Just make sure that you add `tableView` to the closure's capture list to avoid a strong reference cycle. That is done by adding the `[weak tableView]` to the closure.

And then when the cell changes its height you just execute the closure and the cell will be reloaded:

```
func someFunctionThatChangesTheHeight() {
   // change the height
   resizeClosure?()
}
```

Comment: I thought of this once. But indexPath can be changed if we delete cells before that so I would directly call beginUpdate and endUpdate of tableview in my case (there are just five cells). And I believe calling invalidateIntrinsicContentSize should update cell's height for self-sizing table so it's a bug apple should fix.

Comment: Oh, yes, you are totally right, the `indexPath` should be retrieved when the closure is executed (to take deleted and new cells into account). I edited my answer. I agree that Apple should find a solid solution here.